# excel calculating weekly starting value and max for a stock

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have stock market data for a stock as below. It is in a csv format. For each week, I want to find out opening prize on the first day of the week (Monday or Tuesday if Monday is holiday) and the maximum prize within a week. I found out max prize for a week easily using pivot tables. But how could i find starting weekly prizes using excel formula or pivot tables?

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  workweek
23-May-14   86.75   87.82   86.64   87.73   58052491    2014-21
22-May-14   86.66   87.12   86.3    86.75   50218945    2014-21
21-May-14   86.26   86.67   86.01   86.62   49249914    2014-21
20-May-14   86.36   86.63   85.82   86.39   58708986    2014-21
19-May-14   85.41   86.76   85.33   86.37   79439024    2014-21
30-May-14   91.14   92.02   89.84   90.43   141005137   2014-22
29-May-14   89.69   90.98   89.68   90.77   94118633    2014-22
28-May-14   89.43   89.98   89.11   89.14   78921885    2014-22
27-May-14   87.98   89.41   87.95   89.38   87216605    2014-22
```

the table that i want is

```
week    startingvalue  highestvalue
2014-21 85.41         87.82
2014-22 87.98         92.02
```

Comment: I guess your starting values should be 85.41 and 87.98

Comment: You can make use of the `WORKDAY` function which skips weekends and some holidays.  If that is not correct for all your dates, you can create a lookup table with dates to skip.